# make c# program an .exe file

Tags: c#, console-application, exe

I wrote a program that I need to use without the `Visual Studio`. I found the `.exe` file from the debug folder in the bin folder, I tried to use it but it closed just after I tried.

What do I need to do in order to keep it open after it finishes?

Thank you :)

Comment: is it a console application?

Comment: Add a Console.ReadKey(). so it will wait till you press a key

Comment: I think title and question are a little off...

Answer (score 3):

You can write this after your code:

[`Console.ReadKey();`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

or

[`Console.ReadLine();`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

or even

[`Console.Read();`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

It will close when you press any key.

Answer (score 0):

Put a ReadLine at the end of the program

```
public class Program
{
    public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        /*Program logic*/
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to continue...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a readkey at the end of a console application to have the window stay open untill you press any key

Console.ReadKey();